# Vertically align two elements if one is in variable width wrapper

Tags: html, css

I want to have buttons at the side of a paragraph, vertically aligned with elements in that paragraph:

```
<div style="width:20%">
  This is an example text. This is an example text. This is an example text. This is 
  an example text. This is an <span>A</span> <button>Aligned with A</button> example text. This is an example text. 
  This is an example text. This <span>B</span> <button>Aligned with B</button> is an example text. This is an example 
  text. This is an example text. This is an example text. This <span>C</span><button>Aligned with C</button> is an
  example text. This is an example text. 
</div>
```

In this example, I want to have one button vertically aligned with each of the  elements in the text. I cannot set the vertical position fixed because they number of rows in the text varies with actual width of the wrapper div, and I cannot use display: table because I don't want a line break in the text paragraph. The output should look like this:

[image: illustration of how it should look like]

Since the width of the wrapper div is determined by the browser, I don't know where the lines break and therefore don't know the vertical alignment of the text. Is there a way to align the buttons with specific  elements in the div?

This is different from just vertically aligning two columns since the text paragraph breakpoints are independent of the button occurrences on the right.

Comment: why the duplicate and the downvote? if there is something unclear please ask to clarify @connexo

Comment: Do the buttons have the same known width? If so, you can `float` them to `right` and then move past the right container edge via negative `margin-right`

Comment: The width of the button is known, how would I move the content after the button 'past the right container', could you provide code?

Comment: Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n8sd479r/ (hope I understood the problem correctly)

Comment: this works, do you mind pasting your code as response here so i can accept?

Comment: I would post it, but it seems that the question is already closed, so I just can't:(. I agree that it is definitely _NOT the duplicate_ of the suggested "already answered" question, so I nominated it for reopening.

Comment: This question seems much more relevant here than the suggested "duplicate": https://stackoverflow.com/q/48504231/2533215

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use display:table property and make your div's behave like a HTML table.
See docs https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

And use `vertical-align` to align your items.

```css
.paragraph-wrap {
  display: table;
}
.paragraph {
  display:table-row;
}
.paragraph > *{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph-wrap">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>This is an example text.</p>
    <span><button>Button</button></span>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>This is an example text.  This is an example text. This is an example text. This is an example text.</p>
    <span><button>Button</button></span>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>This is an example text.</p>
    <span><button>Button</button></span>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p>This is an example text.</p>
    <span><button>Button</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this almost works except the linebreaks. is there a way to start the new paragraphs without starting a new line, as in my graphic?

Comment: Yes, simply wrap your paragraphs with a `div`, like: `<div class="paragraph">
    <div><p>[...]</p><p>[...]</p><p>[...]</p><p>[...]</p><p>[...]</p></div>
    <span>[...]</span>
  </div>`

Comment: i mean no linebreak between two <div class="paragraph"> so that the text inside paragraph-wrap doesn't have linebreaks, like in my example graphic, any idea how to do that?

Comment: I've updated my question to make this more clear

Comment: Where are you inserting the button? please update your html code.

Comment: I added them after the <span> elements although they should appear on the side of the text as in my graphic. Any ideas how I could do this?